# C# Active Directory query to get attribute values not working

Tags: c#, active-directory

I've been trying for three days to query an Active Directory user's extended attributes values. It works on my dev machines but on the production server it does not work. It only returns a few attributes.

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP"]);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(de);
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeMobile");
SearchResultCollection result2 = search.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult sr in result2)
{
   if (sr.Properties["employeeNumber"].Count > 0)
   {
       var employeeMobile = sr.Properties["employeeMobile"][0].ToString();
   }
}
```

The code works perfectly on my local machine. On production it only returns a few attributes.
The attribute value that I want, `employeeMobile`, is not in the list.

I found a piece of code which, when run on the server, returns all attribute names:

```
List<string> allAttributes = new List<string>();
var context21 = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Forest, "Domain");

using (var schema = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectorySchema.GetSchema(context21))
{
   var userClass = schema.FindClass("user");

   foreach (ActiveDirectorySchemaProperty property in userClass.GetAllProperties())
   {
       strattrib += property.Name + "<br/>";
   }
}
```

I am confused about what is going on. I tried many suggestions from Stackoverflow, including adding this line:

```
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeMobile");
```

It does not show any values.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Is the app running under a different user account in production? Maybe that user only has permission to read certain attributes: https://morgantechspace.com/2016/05/how-to-grant-permission-for-specific-ad-attribute.html

Comment: So who can view what attributes are also controlled by permission levels ? I never heard of that.

Comment: The link above describes how to update permissions by attribute using the AD Users and Computers tool. If you only want to _view_ permissions, click the "View" button instead of "Add". Only users with appropriate permissions to AD can view the permissions, so you may need to talk to your AD administrator if you get stuck.

Comment: You're not showing the query filter in your code. Are you intending to loop through every object on the domain? Or do you actually have a filter that limits the results? Note that if the attribute has no value, the attribute will not exist in the search results, and that's normal. So make sure you're looking up a user who actually has that attribute populated.